# BATCH file to move files by comparing strings and date + time on file names

Tags: batch-file

I have two folders.

folder1: `C:\one\firstfolder`
files:
`111-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSms`
`222-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSms`
or any value on first 3 digits and date and time.

folder2: `C:\two\secondfolder`
files:
`111-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSms`
`222-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSms`
or any value on first 3 digits and date and time.

The requirement I have is to compare the second folder files with first folder files.

(If first three digit code is same in both files and folder1 file time stamp is before the folder2 file timestamp, No need to process the files)
 else
((If no files in folder1) or (if  first three digit code is same and folder1 file time stamp is after the folder2 file timestamp, we need to move those files to other folder called C:\two\secondfolder\work)).

Comment: Please regard that SO is not a code writing service; so share what you have tried so far and describe where you're stuck by editing your post; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also cater for a situation where there is more than 1 file matching the first part of the filename.

But it's untested:

```
@echo off
set "target=C:\two\secondfolder\work"
set "source1=C:\one\firstfolder"
set "source2=C:\two\secondfolder"
if exist "%source2%\*-*" dir "%source1%" /b /a-d >nul 2>&1 || move "%source2%\*-*" "%target%\" >nul
for /f "tokens=1-2,* delims=-" %%a in ('dir "%source1%\*-*" /b /a-d ') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-2,* delims=-" %%x in ('dir "%source2%\%%a-*" /b /a-d ') do (
      if %%b%%c GTR %%y%%z (
         if exist "%source1%\%%a-%%b-%%c" move "%source1%\%%a-%%b-%%c" "%target%\" >nul
         move ""%source2%\%%x-%%y-%%z" "%target%\" >nul
      )
  )
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tested this... files are not moving from source2 to target if no files in source1. Please help me where do I need to change the logic.

Comment: Do the filenames in source2 have a hyphen in them?

Comment: Yes. file name format is 222-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSms in both source folders.

Comment: If the file is only in source2 then it will move.  Or it does in my test.  What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, Let me send logic again, Requirement is to compare files on source1, source2 and move all files from source2 to target only If (no files on source1) or ((if first three digit code of both files is same) and (source2 file time stamp is greater than the source1 file time stamp)) .

Comment: Add this line below the set commands and tell me what it shows on the console when you get the prompt.  `dir "%source1%" /b /a-d&pause`

Comment: It displayed file name of source1.

Comment: I'm not clear.  Is there a file inside and it displayed the filename?

Comment: yes, file was there inside the source1, and after adding dir "%source1%" /b /a-d&pause command at the end of the bat file, it displayed that file name.

Comment: Your logic says `If (no files on source1)` so it is not moving the files in source2 because there is a file in source1

Comment: after logic there is 'or' . so if no files inside source1, all files inside source2 should move to target. if there are files inside source1, we need to check first 3 digits of source1 file names and source2 file names, If both are same, we need to check date and time stamp details on source1 file names and source2 file names. if source2 datetime is grater than source1 datetime then only we need to move source2 files to target. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  When there are no files in source1?

Comment: I have modified code and now it is working fine as expected. Thank you so much for your help on this.                                                                 

set "source1=C:\two\secondfolder"
set "source2=C:\one\firstfolder"                                                                            if exist "%source1%\*-*" dir "%source2%" /b /a-d >nul 2>&1 || move "%source1%\*-*" "%target%\" >nul

      if %%b%%c LSS %%y%%z